# Coming back from Camera Intent crashes Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I have an Activity that launches a Camera Intent like this (nothing special):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  filename);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Than I get the result in `onActivityResult()` and set the bitmap to an ImageView. Again, nothing special.

The problem is that the Camera app is always in landscape. So if the user keeps the device in the horizontal orientation when they hit OK to send it back to my Activity, and my Activity was previously in portrait, then it crashes my activity because it has to rebuild it. If you tilt the device to portrait orientation before you tap OK in the camera, then it does not crash. How do I get around this?

Comment: Not directly related to this question, but I had a similar problem and it wasn't my code. I was using Android 4.2 on a Nexus Mobile (maguro), which somehow made the camera internals all wonky. Flashing on a factory image of 4.3 fixed all this. Be sure to look up your testing device if you're having camera issues!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override the `onSaveInstanceState` method to persist the settings of your activity before fit rotates. Then, in the onCreate method, you can check to see if the `Bundle` argument is null. If not, then you are recreating your activity and should load the saved settings from it.

Comment: This worked great. I've used this way before but I thought there might be a...well...lazier way since it seems like coming back from camera intents is a common, simple task. Thank you!

Comment: And for future viewers, you can also access the Bundle in `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle bundle)`, which I ended up doing.

Answer (score 7):

The quick and dirty route would be to handle the orientation change yourself. If your application doesn't have a different layout for landscape and portrait, then this is a good route to take. Here's how.

Add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your Activity in the `AndroidManifest`.

The other thing you can do is make sure your `onSaveInstanceState` is persisting the camera data and any other data you may be using so that when the application reloads itself, you can reload that data in `onRestoreInstanceState`. If you share your LogCat errors, you'd probably see a `NullPointerException` which is because the data is being lost on the rotate. I'd put my money its the camera data.

Comment: your quick and dirty route was excellent! solved my problem in 20 seconds

Answer (score 2):

In 2022, new android phones especially samsung devices do not work well with "orientation"

For new android versions, we should use **screenSize** along with orientation

like below

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
```

Comment: It worked in my case! Great and Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really need landscape support for your application, you can also block the activity to portrait mode and you don't have to manage the orientation changes.. you can do that in manifest by setting the `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` attribute to your activity.

If you want to have support for landscape too, then I'm afraid that you have to take a look at Brigham's answer .